# ListView in Django Assistance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

OK, so I have just done a rather extensive Django tutorial online and wanted to dive into my first project to see how I would go.

I started off alright and then hit a pretty big road block that I am trying to overcome with no luck, so if you guys could help I will be forever in your debt!

So the project itself is simply making a website for a few of my mates where we can login and view some stats on bets we have with each other.

What I have done so far:

I created two models in models.py with the following code:

```
   from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.

    class Team(models.Model):
        team_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
        wins = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        losses = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Predictions(models.Model):
        combined_teams = models.CharField(max_length=800)
        player_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
        predicted_wins = models.PositiveIntegerField()

        def __str__ (self):
            return self.player_name
```

I created a login screen, this is the first screen the user will come to (not relevant for the question)

I created a static folder with some css styling for a couple of the pages and made some minor changes to the settings files.

I then went on to setup my views.py file and a couple of urls.py files too, as follows:

```
###VIEWS.PY####

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Predictions, Team

class WelcomeView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'merchbet/welcome.html'

class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'merchbet/home.html'

class PredictionListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):    
    model = Predictions


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Predictions.objects.order_by('-player_name')

class GalleryView(LoginRequiredMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = 'merchbet/gallery.html'
```

#### URLS.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth.urls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('account/profile/', include('merchbet.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

#### URLS.PY### IN MY APP FOLDER

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'merchbet'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.WelcomeView.as_view(), name='welcome'),
    path('home/', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('predictions/', views.PredictionListView.as_view(), name='prediction_list'),
    path('gallery/', views.GalleryView.as_view(), name='gallery')
```

I then executed the following script, so that I could load up my friends "predictions" for our NBA bets this season with the following program:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','mysite.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from merchbet.models import Predictions, Team

predictions = ['Burger', 'Houston Rockets and Oklahoma City Thunder', 101,
    'Buzz','Houston Rockets and Boston Celtics', 115, 'Kimon', 'Sacramento Kings and Atlanta Hawks', 44,
    'Muller','Utah Jazz and Boston Celtics', 118, 'Barlow', 'Los Angeles Lakers and Milwaukee Bucks', 102,
    'Larter','Golden State Warriors and Atlanta Hawks', 83, 'Hume', 'Los Andeles Lakers and Philadelphia 76ers',
    104]

def add_predictions():

    for index, entry in enumerate(predictions):

        if index < len(predictions)-2:

            if (type(predictions[index+2]) == type(1)):

                player_name = predictions[index]
                combined_teams = predictions[index+1]
                predicted_wins = predictions[index+2]

                preds = Predictions.objects.get_or_create(player_name=player_name,combined_teams=combined_teams,predicted_wins=predicted_wins)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Populating the databases...Please Wait")
    add_predictions()
    print('Populating Complete')
```

The above worked fine and I can see in my Django Admin view of the site that there are 7 objects of the Predictions class all named after the "player_name" variable as it is the primary key:

So after all of this I am trying to simply use a for loop in an html document, that will help to print out the "player_name" and then I can show the "combined_teams" and "predicted_wins" but I just can not get it to work.

```
{% for prediction in prediction_list %}
<h1>{{ prediction.player_name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

I have put a heap of effort into this post, so I am hoping some genius out there can lend a hand!

edit: I know the colour of the text is white, it is against a black background, so that isn't an issue :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't really said what the problem is. What page are you going to? What do you see? What template is that snippet from and where is the rest of it?

Comment: Thanks, have updated that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `object_list` instead of `prediction_list` for `merchbet/prediction_list.html`, like this:

```
{% for prediction in object_list %}
    <h1>{{ prediction.player_name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

For more details, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU!